# YUI 3 Selector for multiple class names

Tags: yui, css-selectors, yui3

I have a bunch of divs like this:

```
<div class="bear"></div>
<div class="dog"></div>
```

How do I get a nodelist that includes all divs with class of bear and dog? I tried:

```
Y.get(".bear .dog").each(function() {

});
```

But it returns null. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on how CSS selectors work, it should be `.bear, .dog`

Answer (score 6):

Along with VoteyDisciple's answer, you should change the `get` to `all`.

For example:

```
YUI().use('node',function(Y) {
   console.log(Y.get(".bear, .dog").size());  // prints out 1
   console.log(Y.all(".bear, .dog").size());  // prints out 2
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
YUI().use('node',function(Y) {
   console.log(Y.get(".bear + .dog").size());  
   console.log(Y.all(".bear + .dog").size());  
});
```

This could be done to select a node which has both bear and dog as classes.